# Tag Synonym: "Container" and "Containers"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I do not have enough points on either tag to suggest a synonym properly, but anyone here who does should:

- [container](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/container)
- [containers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/containers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I’ve created [the corresponding suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/container/synonyms).

Comment: Synonym created, "containers" merged into "container".